# (Unity) Trouble making double-jump happen after second press. It keeps happening with the initial jump

Tags: unity-game-engine, if-statement

As the title suggests, I am trying to make a double jump in my Character Controller. The problem is, that using my code the character makes one big jump instead of making a second one.

Here is my code:

```
        if (m_Grounded && jump)
        {
            // Add a vertical force to the player.
            m_Grounded = false;
            m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, m_JumpForce));
            canDoubleJump = true;

        } else if (canDoubleJump)
        {
            m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(transform.up * m_Thrust, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            canDoubleJump = false;
        }
```

the defined variables are:

```
bool canDoubleJump;
public float m_Thrust = 200f;
[SerializeField] private float m_JumpForce = 400f;
```

What I have tried so far:

I tried adding the same Vector2 jumpForce in to the double jump place, but then it's just one giant jump even bigger than right now.

I tried changing else if to

```
else if (canDoubleJump && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
```

Nothing seems to work. All ideas are appreciated <3

**EDIT**

I somehow fixed this problem with this code if anyone ever needs:

```
// If the player should jump...
        if (m_Grounded && jump)
        {
            // Add a vertical force to the player.
            m_Grounded = false;
            m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(transform.up * m_JumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            canDoubleJump = true;

        }
        else if (canDoubleJump && !m_Grounded && jump)
        {
            m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(transform.up * m_JumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            canDoubleJump = false;
        }
```

Now the only problem left is adding touches to the physics, but the idea works.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the `jump` variable do? Because this entire if statement needs to be inside another one that goes like

```
if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
{
```

That way there is no chance of it being pressed twice in case you did the `jump` condition the wrong way.

If that doesn't work or if that's already how it is set up, try adding this to the `else if` condition

```
} else if (canDoubleJump && ! m_Grounded)
```

I'm just throwing in ideas as I'm confused why it's not working as-is.

Comment: Im quite positive it has something to do with AddForce, because when I implemented _(canDoubleJump && ! m_Grounded)_ like you suggested, it makes one giant jump.

Comment: This helped me find the right direction, thanks!

Comment: Glad you figured it out! And thank you for making an edit for future visitors <3

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not very clear but you can use this code it works fine for me
When the jump is called the first time, it jumps once and when it is called and the player doesn't touch the ground, it only jumps one more jump

```
public Rigidbody2D m_Rigidbody2D;
public float m_Thrust = 400;
public bool isGrounded;
public bool TowJump;
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground"){
        isGrounded = true;
        TowJump = false;
    }
}
void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground"){
        isGrounded = false;
    }
}
public void Jumped()
{
    if(TowJump == false && isGrounded == false)
    {
        m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(transform.up * m_Thrust, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        TowJump = true;
    }
    if(isGrounded == true)
    {
        m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(transform.up * m_Thrust, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Note, you must tag the floor with the name "Ground"

**EDIT**

The code works without problems, try to follow the steps as shown in the picture

**Player**
[image]

**Ground**
[image]

Comment: I tried implementing your code, but it doesn't seem to work for me. The player can't even jump the first time, it sticks to the ground.

Comment: I did exactly like in your photos, yet the player stays on the ground and only the jump animation starts but the player never leaves the ground to go up.

Comment: If the error is not in the code you wrote, you may find the error somewhere else, for example another code to stop the player at a certain point

Comment: Attach illustrations inside your question to help you solve it as quickly as possible