# How to fix the ground in unity 2d

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

Um I'm making a game in unity I got a problem I made a picture as the ground but it doesn't work  I put if to default and put what is ground to default to I use rigid body as physics and I already put a collision box and collision circle

Comment: Add more detail please

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not a clear question
But be sure to add the rigidbody to the ground and the box colliser for the player and the ground

You can review the images in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71156398/unity-trouble-making-double-jump-happen-after-second-press-it-keeps-happening?answertab=active#tab-top) showing how you can add the rigidbody and the box collider

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the responder above me, even if you did add the colliders, you may not have made the right size.